# Spring Web Application gives 404 only when I use multiple named queries

Tags: java, spring, jpa, web-applications, named-query

this problem is driving me mad. I am making a web application using Spring with JPA. The problem is in my code below.I can deploy my web app perfectly to my localhost and to AWS when the code looks like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "DayTotalPeople.updateTotal", query = "update DayTotalPeople d set d.totalPeople =?1 where d.date =?2 AND d.venue =?3")

public class DayTotalPeople {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private LocalDate date;

  private Integer totalPeople;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "venue_id")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Venue venue;

  public DayTotalPeople() {}

  public DayTotalPeople(LocalDate date, Integer totalPeople, Venue venue) {
    this.date = date;
    this.totalPeople = totalPeople;
    this.venue = venue;
  }

//getters & setters

}
```

However when I add in another named query for the class as shown below, I get a 404 when I try access the application on localhost and AWS.

```
 @Entity
 @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "DayTotalPeople.updateTotal", query = "update DayTotalPeople d set d.totalPeople =?1 where d.date =?2 AND d.venue =?3"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DayTotalPeople.findSumPeopleByVenueAndDateBetween", query = "select sum(d.totalpeople) from DayTotalPeople d where d.venue=?1 and d.date between ?2 and ?3")
})
public class DayTotalPeople {
.....
```

I don't understand how this is happening at all. Can anyone explain why I can't even access the home page due to the above? Thanks!

Comment: `select sum(d.totalpeople)` in second query should be `select sum(d.totalPeople)` (capital P in People). You have erroneous named query -> application context fails to load -> web context fails to deploy

Comment: Thanks so much, I wouldn't have noticed!